# How do I generate a drop down from a database table?

Tags: php, html

My drop down is blank as shown below:

[image: Blank Drop Down]

I tried to generate this drop down using the code below:

```
<?php
$mysqli = NEW MYSQLI('localhost', 'root', '','staff');
$resultSet = $mysqli->query("Select tripid from college");

?>

<label for="">Trip ID</label>
<p>
    <select name="tripid" id="tripid" style="width: 300px">
    <option value='-1' selected>Trip ID</option>
   
<php?
while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()){
    $tripid = $rows['$tripid'];
    echo "<option value='$tripid'>$tripid</option>";
}
?>

    </select>
```

Comment: `['$tripid']` ??? `'$tripid'` is a string

Comment: I've edited your question to make the picture visible, format the code to be readable, and remove the tags for javascript, mysql, and forms since this question has nothing to do with any of those things

Comment: If your `option` element `value` is the same as the text, you don't actually need to specify the value attribute at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's generating something but it's apparently blank.  It would be really helpful to see what the generated HTML looks like instead of a picture of an HTML element.  The code is important here, not what it looks like.

However, I suspect it's just rendering these literal strings:

```html
<option value='$tripid'>$tripid</option>
<option value='$tripid'>$tripid</option>
<option value='$tripid'>$tripid</option>
```

I also suspect that `$rows['$tripid']` should be `$rows['tripid']` since it's unlikely that you have key name with `$` in it like a PHP variable.

In your PHP code you need to concatenate the HTML string with the PHP variables, like this:

```php
while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()){
    $tripid = $rows['tripid'];
    echo "<option value='" . $tripid . "'>" . $tripid . "</option>";
}
```

now it *should* render the actual variable content, like this:

```html
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
```

Comment: It works now. The issue was  this: I also suspect that $rows['$tripid'] should be $rows['tripid'] since it's unlikely that you have key name with $ in it like a PHP variable. I removed the dollar sign and it worked like a charm. Thank you mate!